# Python Tkinter : AttributeError: Button instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I don't know why this is giving me an attribute error. I want my `blah()` function to shuffle the cards. I'm calling the builtin function `shuffle()` from `random`.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui1.py", line 105, in blah
    shuffle(cards)
AttributeError: Button instance has no __call__ method
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
def blah():
    global card_count
    global path
    shuffle(cards)
    card_count = 0
    path = generate_paths(cards)
    print "Cards Shuffled"

shuffle = Button(frame_buttons, text = "SHUFFLE",height = 2, width =  10,command =blah)
shuffle.grid(row = 2 , padx = 40, pady = 40)
```

Comment: Can you please add the part of the code where `Button` is defined and/or imported?

Comment: `Button` is a class in `tkinter`.

Answer (score 2):

`shuffle` is the name of the function in `random`. However, it's also the name of the `Button`. Change the `Button`'s name to something like `shuffle_button` and you should be fine.

Comment: You are pointing out an other problem in the code. But the the error message indicates that Button has also been overloaded.

Comment: It's saying that `shuffle`, an instance of `Button`, doesn't have a defined behavior for being called as a function. The error is appearing in `blah()` with `shuffle(cards)`. The `Button` called `shuffle` isn't a function that can be called with an argument of `cards`; it's just a `Button`. A new name that doesn't override `shuffle` should fix the issue.